# Missing attributes while copying features from a shapefile to PostGIS layer QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'm trying to copy some features from a shapefile into a PostGIS layer loaded in QGIS. I followed the steps bellow.

1. Select and copy features from SHP.
2. activate editing of destination layer and paste copied features.
3. The process completes successfully and the geometric part is passed, but the attribute part is missing.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you need to set up your destination table with the same attributes (and data types) as the table you are copying from. Do this prior to the copy/paste.

Comment: like you said no matched attribute names, stupid mistake ^^